# SPA with front end routing with sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, single-page-application

I'm building a front end app that has a front end router.

This works until someone presses enter on the url bar or refreshes the page and then the request goes to the backend and of course sinatra doesn't know what to do with it as it's a front end route.

How do I deal with this?

So I just re-direct any and all requests to index or somthing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I just tried this:

```
get /[^\/]/ do
    erb :index
end
```

and that seems to work and it doesn't interfere with other routes.